# Python: ways to vectorize "apply a power function with random power to each row in NumPy array"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I would like to find efficient ways to do the following operation:

1. I have a vector of known values, which will be the first row in the following array mentioned.
2. I would like to create an array. For each row other than the first row, it is essentially the first row applied with a power function with a random power.

For example, we have a 3x2 array.
The first row is known: [0,1,2].

Then for the second row, generate a random power, let it be 0.5, then the second row is: [0^0.5,1^0.5,2^0.5].

Now for the third row, generate a random power, let it be 3, then the third row is: [0^3,1^3,2^3].

I can do this easily with for loop. But I am wondering if there is any efficient way to vectorize it (or just efficient enough without vectorization).

Sample code:

```
beta=np.zeros((3,1000+1))
beta[0]=np.append(0,np.random.uniform(0,1,1000))

for i in range(1,3,1):
    p=np.random.uniform(0,2)
    beta[i]= beta[0]**p
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: you could assign `beta[0]` to local variable before `for`-loop - and may work little faster because it will not have to search it in array in every loop.

Comment: maybe first you should copy `beta[0]` to all rows, and next generate list `all_p` with `p` for all rows (with `1` for first row) and later calculate `beta ** all_p`  - something like `array([[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]]) ** array([1, 0.5, 3])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcasting to the rescue:

```py
In [2]: beta = np.array([0, 1, 2])

In [3]: lo, hi, num_rows_desired = 0, 3, 3

In [4]: exps = np.random.uniform(lo, hi, num_rows_desired)

In [5]: exps[0] = 1  # Set the first 'power' to 1

In [6]: beta ** exps[:, None]
Out[6]:
array([[0.        , 1.        , 2.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356],
       [0.        , 1.        , 8.        ]])
```

Where `lo` and `hi` are the bounds for your uniformly distributed exponents, and `num_rows_desired` is however many exponents you want to apply to `beta` (which will result in that many rows).

This is probably the way you want to do this, since creating your entire `beta` array in memory is wasteful. Simply generate your initial row vector for `beta` and let broadcasting do the work for you.

Comment: could you also use values from question `[0,1,2]` and `[1,0.5,3]`? it would be simpler compare solution with question.

Comment: I guess, sure...

Comment: first example works for me also without first `None` - `x ** exps[:, None]`

Comment: second example works for me also without changing shape `x = np.array([0, 1, 2])` and with `x.shape[0]` instead of `x.shape[1]`